# CSS decorated button becomes inactive and unclickeable

Tags: jquery, css, button, click, submit

After customizing a button with CSS the decoration is applied properly but the button becomes inactive, I cannot click on it and it won't submit.

Here is the code:

```
.addToCart {
width: 100px;
border-radius: 4px/4px;
border: 2px #E8CD00;
height:20px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: center;
font-family: "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 1px;
background-color: #E8CD00;
color: black;
}

<form name="cartAdding">
<input type="hidden" name="productid" />
<input type="hidden" name="command" />
</form>
<input type="submit" value="ADD TO CART" class="addToCart" onclick="addtocart(<?php $itemId?>)" />
```

Comment: Also `<?php $itemId?>` likely isn't what you're after, try: `<?= $itemId ?>` to output the value of the variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to move the `input` into the `form` element.

```
<form name="cartAdding">
    <input type="hidden" name="productid" />
    <input type="hidden" name="command" />
    <input type="submit" value="ADD TO CART" class="addToCart" onclick="addtocart(<?= $itemId ?>)" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

Put the button inside the

```
<form>
```

tags. Also keep in mind that clicking the button will submit the form, and unless your Javascript function returns false, you may see unexpected activity.

Answer (score 2):

You need to place your submit button inside the form, like this:

```
<form name="cartAdding">
  <input type="hidden" name="productid" />
  <input type="hidden" name="command" />
  <input type="submit" value="ADD TO CART" class="addToCart" onclick="addtocart(<?php $itemId?>)" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Actually, everyone else is more correct - the `<input type="submit" />` needs to be inside the `<form></form>` tags. There still remains the issue of the odd php code too.

Check your resulting HTML - you forgot an `echo` on your `onclick` handler.

```
    <input type="submit" value="ADD TO CART" class="addToCart" onclick="addtocart(<?php $itemId?>)" />
                                                                                        ^^ - add echo here
```

Youre resulting HTML is probably like this:

```
    <input type="submit" value="ADD TO CART" class="addToCart" onclick="addtocart()" />
```

or worse, has some PHP error message in it. Either way, the JS function being called `addtocart()` is likely dieing because it is not getting a proper argument.

Answer (score 0):

Your button is being pressed, check  the syntax on your addtocart method, I changed the code a little bit and it works perfectly. Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZC2M5/)

```
<form name="cartAdding">
<input type="hidden" name="productid" />
<input type="hidden" name="command" />
</form>
<input type="submit" value="ADD TO CART" class="addToCart" onclick="alert('click!!');" />
```